# Strong params, unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue with strong parameters.

My permuted parameters are:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user_id, :topic_id).merge(:user_id => get_user.id)
end
```

The parameters being passed are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"5+OEnLgihamJC37BSn4r/spoiRmccJzHhe6eaeC2Fuc=",
"post"=>{"topid_id"=>"10",
"content"=>"awfawfaw"}}
```

And the create function is:

```
def create
    post = Post.new(post_params)
    if post.valid? && post.save
       redirect_to :controler => :topic, :action => :show, :topic => post.topic.id
    end
end
```

[image]

That is the error in the console. I want to know why it is not permitting `topic_id`.

Comment: You have a typo. Your log shows `topid_id` instead of `topic_id`.

Comment: God bless your eye for detail ;)

Comment: I *REALLY* helps us help you when you do NOT use a screen grab for errors or text. Instead, copy and paste the text, making sure its formatted in a reasonably readable way.

Comment: @FrancisMalloch I think you have mistyped `topic_id` attribute in your form once cross check with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your permitted params:

what you have is:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user_id, :topic_id).merge(:user_id => get_user.id)
end
```

and It should be:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user_id, :topid_id).merge(:user_id => get_user.id)
end
```

But it depends on your model what name of attribute you have in your model. Either you have to change in the form in typo in the form, or either you have to change everywhere else.